# Formulário em loop no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, formulário

Bom dia, estou tentando fazer um formulário em um loop para cada linha da tabela, quando o usuário clica no botão em uma linha, pega os dados dessa linha e carrega em outra página, mas por algum motivo no loop os inputs não ficam dentro do form, segue o código do loop:

```
if($total_row > 0)
      {
       foreach($data as $row)
       {
        $output .= '
    <tr>
             <form  action="monitor/info" method="POST">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
             <td> <input type="text" readonly="" style="width: 310px"  name="nome" id="nome" value="'.$row->nome.'" /></td>
             <td> <input type="text" readonly="" style="width: 80px" name="usuariox" id="usuariox" value="'.$row->usuario_x.'" /></td>
             <td> <input type="text" readonly="" style="width: 100px" name="aspect" id="aspect" value="'.$row->aspect.'" /></td>
             <td> <input type="text" readonly="" name="supervisor" id="supervisor" value="'.$row->supervisor.'" /></td>
             <td> <input type="text" readonly="" style="width: 70px" name="setor" id="setor" value="'.$row->setor.'" /></td>  
             <td> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Criar Laudo"></td>
             </form>
            </tr>
';
       }
      }
      else
      {
       $output = '
       <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="5">Nehum registro encontrado!</td>
       </tr>
       ';
      }
```

Segue no browser como interpreta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode dizer onde estou errando?

Comment: não entendi o seu loop... como você faz um loop sem um for, while etc...?

Comment: começa assim:
      if($total_row > 0)
      {
       foreach($data as $row)
       {
        $output .= '

e termina assim:
';
       }
      }
      else
      {
       $output = '
       <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="5">Nehum registro encontrado!</td>
       </tr>
       ';
      }

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione ao código, assim fica mais fácil de visualizar

Comment: Pergunta foi editada

Comment: Tentei com GET também mas o form ainda fica ali sem nada dentro =(

Comment: um momento, estou formulando uma resposta :D

Comment: a propósito, qual a versão do laravel você está utilizando?

Comment: Versão do laravel 5.7

Answer (score 1):

Se você verificar a documentação do [`<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) verá a seguinte linha:

> **Permitted content**: Zero or more `<td>` and/or `<th>` elements; script-supporting elements (`<script>` and `<template>`) are also allowed.

Ou seja, em um documento HTML válido, apenas os elementos `<th>`, `<td>`, `<script>` e `<template>` são permitidos dentro de um elemento `<tr>`.

Isso significa que, apesar da sua string estar sendo "montada" da maneira que você quer, o navegador faz alterações ao montar a árvore DOM removendo ou alterando código inválido, que é o seu caso.

Uma solução que eu usaria seria utilizar o `<form>` em um lugar válido e utilizar o atributo [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#form) do `<input>` ([compatibilidade](https://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute)) para especificar a qual formulário este `<input>` pertence.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$count = 0;
foreach($data as $row) {
    $count++;
    $output .= <<<HTML
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form id="form-$count" action="monitor/info" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input name="nome" value="{$row->nome}">
                </form>
            </td>
            <td><input name="usuariox" value="{$row->usuariox}" form="form-$count"></td>
            <td><input name="aspect" value="{$row->aspect}" form="form-$count"></td>
            <td><input name="supervisor" value="{$row->supervisor}" form="form-$count"></td>
            <td><input name="supervisor" value="{$row->supervisor}" form="form-$count"></td>
            <td><input name="setor" value="{$row->setor}" form="form-$count"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Criar Laudo"></td>
        </tr>
HTML;
}
```

Comment: Esta ´é uma boa solução, mas o formulário é montado em um controller e trás no blade um json assim:
function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
{
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('live_search.action') }}",
   method:'GET',
   data:{query:query},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
    $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
  }
  });
 }
neste caso como posso montar na requisição ajax os elementos para o formulario?
essa página faz uma pesquisa ao clicar na tecla, por isso tem que ser ajax, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Não entendi a sua dúvida, eu apenas copiei o seu próprio `for` e alterei. A estrutura é do seu próprio código.

Comment: Fiz essa alteração, mas ficou bem lento a busca, deve ter um jeito de capturar o json e montar no formulário no blade, se montar assim no controller ele não funciona

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde amigos, só passando para informar que encontrei uma solução simples para este problema, usei a sessão do javascript, pois o objeto era simples, enviar informações de uma página a outra, despensa o uso de chamada por form, e isso não muda a velocidade da busca, continua a mesma,

```
if($total_row > 0)
      {
       $count = 0;   
       foreach($data as $row)
       {
        $count ++;   
        $output .= '
        <tr>
         <td> <input type="text" readonly="" style="width: 310px"  name="nome'.$count.'" id="nome'.$count.'" value="'.$row->nome.'" /></td>
         <td> <input type="text" readonly="" style="width: 80px" name="usuariox'.$count.'" id="usuariox'.$count.'" value="'.$row->usuario_x.'" /></td>
         <td> <input type="text" readonly="" style="width: 100px" name="aspect'.$count.'" id="aspect'.$count.'" value="'.$row->aspect.'" /></td>
         <td> <input type="text" readonly="" name="supervisor'.$count.'" id="supervisor'.$count.'" value="'.$row->supervisor.'" /></td>
         <td> <input type="text" readonly="" style="width: 70px" name="setor'.$count.'" id="setor'.$count.'" value="'.$row->setor.'" /></td>  
         <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn'.$count.'">Criar Laudo</button></td>

         <script>

              $("#btn'.$count.'").click(function(){
                  localStorage.setItem("nome", $("#nome'.$count.'").val());
                  localStorage.setItem("usuariox", $("#usuariox'.$count.'").val());
                  localStorage.setItem("aspect", $("#aspect'.$count.'").val());
                  localStorage.setItem("supervisor", $("#supervisor'.$count.'").val());
                  localStorage.setItem("setor", $("#setor'.$count.'").val());    
                  window.location.href = "http:...endereço da página";
              });

         </script>

        </tr>
        ';
       }
      }
      else
      {
       $output = '
       <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="5">Nehum registro encontrado!</td>
       </tr>
       ';
      }
```

e resgato essas sessao na outra página com jquery. abç